# Is there a 3rd party sourcebook for Arabian Nights gaming in 4eD&D

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm looking for a sourcebook for Arabian Nights flavor (the more the better). I'm looking for any of the following:

- Monsters
- Classes (new or modified)
- Powers
- Rituals
- Magic Items
- DM advice

On-line resources are also appreciated.

Comment: Who voted that this is subjective and argumentative??

Comment: I really don't see how it is either??

Comment: @Buccaneers Guild - agreed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [a community effort](http://www.enworld.org/forum/4e-fan-creations-house-rules/240388-forked-thread-al-qadim-land-fate-d-d-4th-edition.html) to update the definitive Arabic D&D setting, Al-Qadim, to 4e but it doesn't look like it's gotten much traction.  I did find one guy who posted some [4e Al-Qadim conversions](http://community.livejournal.com/al_qadim/2962.html).

Besides that - I don't know of any third party products.  There are reasonably few GSL products and I don't know of any that touch anything Arabian (one Indian one was as close as it gets).

Comment: What is the Indian one? Is it good?

Comment: Can't speak for its quality, I just saw it in the Paizo store. http://paizo.com/store/games/roleplayingGames/d/4E/skirmisherPublishing